# Arduino stops accepting commands from PS3 in middle.?? although it shows connected?? after particular function?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

please read entirely and sorry but it has to be descriptive. we are using PS3 controller to control our robot, so the problem is that PS3 is getting connected and functions are called when buttons are clicked but we are finding issues that when some functions are called after that Arduino does not accept any command from PS3... we debugged the functions, so the functions are running completely and after that execution comes back to void loop but it stop responding to PS3 commands. It shows that PS3 is still connected but Arduino does not accept command in middle.
we are unable to find where issue lie because some functions are executed properly and after that also PS3 responds, being specific when we call elbowup() or elbowdown() after them Arduino stops responding to PS3.

elbow functions

```
void elbowUP()
{ 
  /*** checking if my shoulder angle is lesser than threshold or no **/

  //elbow UP CODE HERE...

      int min_val= 30;
      int max_val= 140;
      Serial.println("ELBOW UP");
      for(int j=30;j<=max_val;j++)
       {
         ElbowGripperservo.write(j);
         Serial.println(j);
         delay(20);
       }    
    
       Serial.println("coming out of loop");
     //Usb.Task();
     Serial.println("print after usb task");
      
    }
    
    void elbowDown()
    { 
      /*** checking if my shoulder angle is greater than threshold or no **/
      //ELBOW DOWN CODE TO WRITTEN HERE
      int min_val= 30;
      int max_val= 140;
      Serial.println("Elbow Down");
       for(int j=max_val;j>=min_val;j--)
       {
         ElbowGripperservo.write(j);
         Serial.println(j);
         delay(20);
       }   
       Usb.Task(); 
     
    }



        void loop(){
        Usb.Task();
    
     //Serial.println("working in loop");
    
      //By default pistons pins must be at LOW when user not pressing CROSS Button
      //pistonBack();
      //releaseVacuum(); 
        
        int xl, yl, xr, yr;
    
        if (PS3.PS3Connected || PS3.PS3NavigationConnected)
        {
            if (PS3.getAnalogHat(LeftHatX) > 137 || PS3.getAnalogHat(LeftHatX) < 117 || PS3.getAnalogHat(LeftHatY) > 137 || PS3.getAnalogHat(LeftHatY) < 117 || PS3.getAnalogHat(RightHatX) > 137 || PS3.getAnalogHat(RightHatX) < 117 || PS3.getAnalogHat(RightHatY) > 137 || PS3.getAnalogHat(RightHatY) < 117)
            {
                xl = PS3.getAnalogHat(LeftHatX);
                yl = PS3.getAnalogHat(LeftHatY);
    
                if (PS3.PS3Connected)
                { // The Navigation controller only have one joystick
                    xr = PS3.getAnalogHat(RightHatX);
                    yr = PS3.getAnalogHat(RightHatY);
                }
    
                calculate(xl, yl, xr, yr);
            }
    
            // Analog button values can be read from almost all buttons
        if (PS3.getButtonClick(L2) ){
            
           // elbowDown();
            Usb.Task();
    
        }
        else if(PS3.getButtonClick(R2)){
    
          
          shoulderDown();
          Usb.Task();
        
        }
    
            if (PS3.getButtonClick(PS))
            {
                Serial.print(F("\r\nPS"));
                PS3.disconnect();
            }
            else
            {
    
          while(PS3.getButtonClick(TRIANGLE)){
              Usb.Task();
             // createVacuum();    
          }
                if (PS3.getButtonClick(CIRCLE))
                {
                    Serial.print(F("\r\nCircle"));
            releaseVacuum();
                }
          while(PS3.getButtonClick(CROSS)){
              Usb.Task();
              createVacuum();    
          }
    
                if (PS3.getButtonClick(SQUARE))
         {
                    Serial.print(F("\r\nSquare"));
            elbowUP();
            
         }
                if (PS3.getButtonClick(UP))
                {
    
            pistonPush();
                    Serial.print(F("\r\nUp"));
                    if (PS3.PS3Connected)
                    {
                        PS3.setLedOff();
                        PS3.setLedOn(LED4);
                    }
                }
                if (PS3.getButtonClick(RIGHT))
                {
                    Serial.print(F("\r\nRight"));
                    if (PS3.PS3Connected)
                    {
                        PS3.setLedOff();
                        PS3.setLedOn(LED1);
                    }
                }
                if (PS3.getButtonClick(DOWN))
                {
              pistonBack();
                    Serial.print(F("\r\nDown"));
                    if (PS3.PS3Connected)
                    {
                        PS3.setLedOff();
                        PS3.setLedOn(LED2);
                    }
                }
                if (PS3.getButtonClick(LEFT))
                {
                    Serial.print(F("\r\nLeft"));
                    if (PS3.PS3Connected)
                    {
                        PS3.setLedOff();
                        PS3.setLedOn(LED3);
                    }
                }
    
                if (PS3.getButtonClick(L1)){
    
            //Elbow up function to be called here....
            
           // elbowUP();
            Serial.println("after function call");
            Usb.Task();
            Serial.println("after function usb");
    
                }
    
                if (PS3.getButtonClick(L3))
                    Serial.print(F("\r\nL3"));
                if (PS3.getButtonClick(R1)){
    
             // Usb.Task();
              shoulderUp();
              Usb.Task();
            
                }
                    
                if (PS3.getButtonClick(R3))
                    Serial.print(F("\r\nR3"));
    
                if (PS3.getButtonClick(SELECT))
                {
                    Serial.print(F("\r\nSelect - "));
                    PS3.printStatusString();
                }
                if (PS3.getButtonClick(START))
                {
                    Serial.print(F("\r\nStart"));
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }


for confirmation that when we press other buttons some functions get executed properly, i am also adding serial monitor stuff


PS3 Bluetooth Library StartedTable Back--Release Vacuum

PS3 Bluetooth Library StartedTable Back--Release Vacuum

CircleRelease Vacuum
Create vacuum

CircleRelease Vacuum
Create vacuum

CircleRelease Vacuum
Create vacuum
Table Push

UpTable Back--
DownTable Push

UpTable Back--
Down
Right
Left
Right
LeftTable Back--
Down
SquareELBOW UP
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
81
82
83
84
85
86
87
88
89
90
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
100
101
102
103
104
105
106
107
108
109
110
111
112
113
114
115
116
117
118
119
120
121
122
123
124
125
126
127
128
129
130
131
132
133
134
135
136
137
138
139
140
coming out of loop
print after usb task
```

please please a genuine request, help me find issue, please it would be a great favor. sorry for making it too long but please locate issue why Arduino stops accepting PS3 command although it remains connected.

Answer (score 0):

Some questions come to my mind:

1. Are you using interrupts anywhere in your code? If so, make sure they are short and you are not doing any `Serial.println()` inside.
2. Are you confident that the Uno running at 16 MHz has enough computing power for handling the controller, vacuum actuator and your servo motors? The latter are normally time-critical devices and you might be using blocking functions that are consuming too much time. Otherwise, consider migrating your code to a Mega, perhaps?
3. Have you considered using an FSM (Finite States Machine) approx, which normally improves the flow of the execution of code. It seems to me that you need some sort of multitasking capabilities like an RTOS to improve the operability of your application, however, your code is functions-based and doesn't seem very optimized to detect button presses. It will certainly be slow at detecting the next button press since it will take some time to activate your piston, motor, etc.

Bottomline is: you need to improve the flow by thinking of states in your system

Please share your entire code to have a look at the weak points